# go json decoder definition , what should be as input in this case

Tags: go

I have a go code to encode struct to json object.
Can anybody show me how to decode it back?
The thing I don't understand is, to define decoder, what should it be as input?

package main

```
import "encoding/json"
import "bytes"
//import "os"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var emptyAppendEntriesResponse bytes.Buffer
    enc := json.NewEncoder(&emptyAppendEntriesResponse)
    d := map[string]int{"apple": 5, "lettuce": 7}
    enc.Encode(d)



}
```

thanks

Comment: `NewDecoder` takes an `io.Reader`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to decode things back from emptyAppendEntriesResponse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `bytes.Buffer` as both a Reader and Writer, but it's a little easier if you use a `*bytes.Buffer`, since you need to use a pointer anyway.

http://play.golang.org/p/NbK_D-bMML

```
emptyAppendEntriesResponse := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
enc := json.NewEncoder(emptyAppendEntriesResponse)
d := map[string]int{"apple": 5, "lettuce": 7}
enc.Encode(d)

fmt.Println(string(emptyAppendEntriesResponse.Bytes()))

dec := json.NewDecoder(emptyAppendEntriesResponse)

d = map[string]int{}
dec.Decode(&d)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", d)
```

When you're not working directly with io streams, it's usually more convenient to use `json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal`, rather than creating the Encoder and Decoder.

```
d := map[string]int{"apple": 5, "lettuce": 7}
resp, err := json.Marshal(&d)
fmt.Println(string(resp))

d = map[string]int{}
err = json.Unmarshal(resp, &d)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", d)
```